# Can/should we have a tag for questions where OP suspects fallacy in question?

Tags: discussion, tags

One of the things I like about the Computer Science site over StackOverflow in general is that if you mention you are not sure of what you are asking people here people will tend to help you reformulate your question into something of value and then answer it. That was the recent case for me with [How are programming languages and foundations of mathematics related?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9756/268)

One thing I found out with some of the F# people at SO is that if they see a question of merit but that is fallacious and should be reformulated they will suggest the changes in a comment and ask that the question be closed before being answered, and then a new revised question be asked so as not to have the fallacious question appear and have to work to repair it.

As such I would like purpose a tag that tells others that if the question has merit but is fallacious, that it not be answered but have comments suggesting changes so that the OP can close the question and open a new question of more value to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you indicate a fallacy in a question by a tag? Tags indicate what the question is about: [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms), [compilers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers), [authentication](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication), … Whether there is a misconception in the way the question is stated is irrelevant to decide whether the question would interest you, so it's not something that people would search for, subscribe to or ignore. Therefore it's pointless to have as a tag.

This would be a prime example of a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which Stack Exchange strives to avoid.